# Representing a "radiomatrix" question from a survey

Tags: r

Hi I am making a report of a survey where we have what we call a "radiomatrix" and it looks like this.

[alt text http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/9288/radiomatrix.png](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/9288/radiomatrix.png)

Then we import the answers is a table in R into something that looks like this:

```
user    tiramisu  cupcake   chocolate  carrot
test01  loves_it  loves_it  loves_it   hate_it
test02  likes_it  likes_it  loves_it   likes_it
test03  likes_it  loves_it  loves_it   hate_it
```

**What would be the best and most meaningful graphical representation for this?**

Comment: Not programming related?

Comment: Actually I would do it R and I was mainly asking for a piece of code or example that could be run in R and plot the stat. But I understand it can be interpreted as a more generic question. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 3):

One of the things I would do is to constract a contingency table and then perform correspondence analysis (look fot it [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Multivariate.html)), to produce something like [this](http://bm2.genes.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/R_current/library/ca/man/images/plot.ca_002.png)

Another one is that I would try to show correlations between preferences (something like [this](http://addictedtor.free.fr/graphiques/RGraphGallery.php?graph=149))

Perhaps one could also mine association rules, e.g.

`If Loves Tiramisu then hates Cupcake`

If you would like to create mosaic plots with R, check out [this](http://bm2.genes.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/R_current/library/graphics/man/mosaicplot.html).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a "best" representation for any given set of data. It depends on what you're trying to show. Some examples:

- If you want to test the hypothesis that people are extreme about their cake preferences -- that is, that there are very few likes vs. loves/hates -- you could show a plot of preference intensity versus quantity.
- If you want to show that chocolate is more preferred than tiramisu, you could use a simple table that assigns -1 to "hate", 0 to "like", and 1 to "love" to come up with a mean/median score for each dessert.

Comment: What about a multiple histogram, as a barplot ? as in this one: http://img532.imageshack.us/img532/7253/screenshot20100622at120.png

Comment: Those are fine, but consider a table if you're just showing numbers, particularly if there's more than a handful of different cake choices. A bar graph wastes a lot of visual space and is an inefficient representation of data -- for instance, it's not possible to have "2.99" votes for cupcakes, but that's what is suggested when you use one.

Answer (score 0):

A mosaic plot might be interesting. See [here (PDF)](http://rosuda.org/~unwin/Japan2003/UnwinISMTokyoNov03mosaic.pdf) for examples.

Comment: That looks interesting... any example that shows how to generate in R something like this given the table above?